# iPhone Debug Configuration - Provisioning Profile

Tags: iphone, debugging, codesign

I have an iPhone application that I am trying to build and run on debug mode. I am getting a popup box saying:

"A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found."

What could be the problem? I have a provisioning profile that is set up with a specific App ID and in my codesigning I have selected this profile. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Double click the provisioning profile on your mac so that it gets installed in your machine.
2. In XCode, (I assume you are using XCode), double click on the target under "Targets" group  and check whether the code signing is set up properly in the box that opens up there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: that did help. okay so now I am running in debug mode and my console spits this message after it starts running: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found)

Comment: Here is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284277/libxcodedebuggersupport-dylib-is-missing-in-ios-4-2-1-development-sdk

Comment: I couldn't find a cohesive answer from that link.