# _Unwind_SjLj_Resume exception when deleting CoreData objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, gcc

I keep getting a crash that I'm at a loss to debug.   It appears to happen occasionally after deleting Core Data Objects.  I delete in different thread/context and merge back to the main context on the main thread.  It's rare, I can't reproduce it consistently, and the stack trace is completely useless.  This is not a migration issus like other mentions of _Unwind_SjLj_Resume.

From googling around, _Unwind_SjLj_Resume is unwinding an exception.   So The story I've made up is I'm crashing with some exception and this error occurs when the exception gets un-wound...   Any thoughts on how to proceed?

```
#0  0x33bd52d4 in __kill ()
#1  0x33bd52ca in kill ()
#2  0x33bd52bc in raise ()
#3  0x33be9d78 in abort ()
#4  0x33bd7986 in __assert_rtn ()
#5  0x32acab56 in _Unwind_SjLj_Resume ()
#6  0x33a47d56 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#7  0x33a47b8e in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#8  0x33b0e4aa in GSEventRunModal ()
#9  0x33b0e556 in GSEventRun ()
#10 0x32099328 in -[UIApplication _run] ()
#11 0x32096e92 in UIApplicationMain ()
```

Comment: It's now occurring consistently, but not sure what's aggravating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out It was due to an error in my didSave - isDeleted.   I was dispatching file deletion using NSFileManager defaultManager which is not thread safe.  There was no sign of it in my stack traces but I tracked it down by stepping through assembler on the save routine and noticed that the runloop_handle_dispatch function was the last to operate and deduced from there.

Thanks for your help, Bleh!

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing multiple threads, make sure you are locking your persistent store.

It should look similar to this:

```
[self.persistentStoreCoordinator lock];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = //your store;
[context save:&error];

if (error)
    // handle error

[self.persistentStoreCoordinator unlock];
```

Comment: This isn't the problem, the persistent store will be locked by the contexts. Simply using a separate context per thread, as documented by Apple, is fine.

Comment: @paulbailey  At least one context per thread is the fine.  But I can guarantee that you need to lock your store when using multiple contexts.  You will get intermittent crashes otherwise.

Comment: I don't think the lock will help.  I can try, but from the documentation:  "There is no typically no need to use locks with managed object or managed object contexts. However, if you use a single persistent store coordinator shared by multiple contexts and want to perform operations on it (for example, if you want to add a new store), or if you want to aggregate a number of operations in one context together as if a virtual single transaction, you should lock the persistent store coordinator."

Answer (score 0):

You might look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505687/debugging-sigabrt-within-nsmanagedobjectcontext-save) posting. I was experiencing something very similar and was able to track down the cause to a reference to a released object (one that on which dealloc had already been called). As with your case, I was deleting NSManagedObjects. Turning on "Stop on Objective-C Exceptions" allowed me to trap the exception.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone researching this in the future I received this exception and the cause was because I had set a cache name in the FetchedResltsController - the cache was trying to load a row which had been deleted from the database - perhaps the app quit during the delete process. anyways setting the cacheName to nil on the call to initWithFetchRequest sorted my problems.