# Apllictaion getting crash due to file not found warning (Iphone sdk )

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am getting the following warning and the application gets crash after this

Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Developer_4.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148a)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).

If someone has come across the same warning , tell me how to fix this warning .

What i suppose from this warning is the debugger is not ablr to get the libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib file .

Please tell me how to fix this error

Thanks 
Mrugen

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Window > Organizer**, right click on your device and click on "Collect informations".
It will takes 5 minutes and after this step you will be able to debug your app.
If not works, take a look at the bug fixing tool (the live debugging thing view)

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurred to some people while using sdk 4.2.1. A temporary solution that will help you to solve the problem is by creating a symlink to the missing dylib file.

Please refer to the following link for more information:
[libxcodedebuggersupport-dylib-is-missing-in-ios-4-2-1-development-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284277/libxcodedebuggersupport-dylib-is-missing-in-ios-4-2-1-development-sdk)

Hope this helps you.