# Weird log messages when creating SMS using MFMessageComposeViewController (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, sms, warnings, logging, iokit

I'm having some odd log messages come up when I create an sms message in my app, which I don't understand. I've had a look around online for a solutions but I haven't been able to find anything. These are the messages printed:

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.5 (8L1)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit (file not found).
warning: No copy of IOKit.framework/IOKit found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Tried to remove a non-existent library: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.5 (8L1)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit
```

How can I resolve these issues? I tried to find an IOKit framework but there doesn't seem to be one built into Xcode. If I submit my app will it be rejected due to these messages?

Here is the code I'm using to create & show the sms:

```
- (void)smsLocation:(NSString *)locationDetails
{
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
        MFMessageComposeViewController *smsController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
        smsController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        smsController.body = @"Some text";

        [self presentModalViewController:smsController animated:YES];
        [smsController release];
    }
}
```

I also have a delegate method which is:

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "when i create an sms message"?...you can't set/get SMS in your app if you want an app on the store.

Comment: @Mat - using MFMessageComposeViewController you can open a built in sms window that allows you to send SMS messages. It's quite common, and the documentation on apple developer is very good: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009668

Comment: @JonW09 - can you post the code you use to send the SMS?

Comment: @adamsiton I have posted the code I'm using to generate the SMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is a very well known problem. You can read the following posts:

[Unable to read symbols warning after updating to 4.3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974056/unable-to-read-symbols-warning-after-updating-to-4-3-3)

[iPhone app crashes on device, File not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859018/iphone-app-crashes-on-device-file-not-found/5859982#5859982)

[libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib is missing in iOS 4.2.1 development SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284277/libxcodedebuggersupport-dylib-is-missing-in-ios-4-2-1-development-sdk)

Although none of the solutions there worked for me.

However, searching the apple developer forum yields the following answer from one of the apple support team:

> Search here for details, but the short answer is you can ignore...

I guess it's a known bug that doesn't cause any problems - the code worked fine except for the warnings.

By the way, if it really bothers you, you can get rid of at least the first warning by simply copying the file IOKit from:

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.3 (8J2)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A

to:

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.3 (8J2)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/

(Or which ever framework you are using instead of 4.3.3)

Comment: Ok great, thanks for all the info. So it's safe to say I can leave my code alone, and when I submit it the app store for review it shouldn't cause any concern?

Comment: Yes. This code shouldn't cause any problems with the app store review.