# iPhone: receiving warning on clicking uialertview cancel or other button

Tags: iphone

### warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.4 (8K2)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).

```
- (void)showReminder:(NSString *)text
{
    NSLog(@"alert text>>%@",text);
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reminder" 
                                                        message:text delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Snooze",nil];
    [alertView show];

    [alertView release];

}


-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView*)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex]; 

    NSLog(@"alert title>>%@",title);
    if(buttonIndex == 0)  
    {  
        NSLog(@"Button 1 was selected.");  
    }  
    else if([title isEqualToString:@"Snooze"])  
    {  
        NSLog(@"check")
    }

}
```

Comment: its giving me bad excess

Comment: Check at which point the application is crashing by putting breakpoint inside **clickedButtonAtIndex** method.

Comment: Also it does not seems fine that you are checking buttonIndex in first condition and a string comparison in second condition.

Comment: its crashing when i click on either ok or snooze button on alert i.e its not entering the delegate method mentioned above...

Comment: Did you put breakpoint at following line : NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

Comment: yes but control does not reach there.... warning comes before entering into clickedButtonatIndex

Comment: What exact message you get in log?

Comment: Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.4 (8K2)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).

Comment: i am facing the same problem plz let me know if u find the answer ...thanks

Comment: thanks to every one i finally got the solution .....it was a memory management issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have this instead:

```
- (void)showReminder:(NSString *)text {

   NSLog(@"alert text>>%@",text);
   UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reminder" 
                                                 message:text 
                                                 delegate:self
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                 otherButtonTitles:@"Snooze",nil];
   [alertView show];

   [alertView release];

}


-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView*)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{    

    if(buttonIndex == 0)  {  
       NSLog(@"Button 1 was selected.");  
    }  
    else if(buttonIndex == 1){  
        NSLog(@"check")
    }

}
```

when `buttonIndex` is 1 then that is your snooze button. If you have other alerts then just apply a tag in showReminder `alertView.tag = 1` and in your `clickedButtonAtIndex` add an outer if saying

```
if(alertView.tag==1)
```

And for that error check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284277/libxcodedebuggersupport-dylib-is-missing-in-ios-4-2-1-development-sdk). They seem to have solved how to fix the missing symlink you need

Answer (score 0):

Respond to Alert Button Selection

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate> {
```

Create UIAlertview

```
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello World!"
                                              message:@"This is your first UIAlertview message."
                                             delegate:self
                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Button 1"
                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Button 2", @"Button 3", nil];
[message show];
```

And

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if([title isEqualToString:@"Button 1"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Button 1 was selected.");
    }
    else if([title isEqualToString:@"Button 2"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Button 2 was selected.");
    }
    else if([title isEqualToString:@"Button 3"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Button 3 was selected.");
    }
}
```