# "Symbols not found" when using 'rake device'

Tags: xcode, rubymotion

I am getting the following error when running `rake device` on any RubyMotion project

```
*** symbols not found in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/7.0': debugger might be slow to attach
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Symbols` folder is missing in the `DeviceSupport/7.0` folder.

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/7.0
sudo ln -s ../../Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk Symbols
```

After that you should have the following symbolic link in your `7.0` folder

```
Symbols -> ../../Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk
```

That solved it for me.

---

*There was a similar problem in iOS 4.2.1 Xcode 4.3.2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4453666/1095510*